# How did I get informations on the module I'm writing?

Tags: python, shell

I'm writing my first complete python project with Vim. As I was modifying a
file I accidentally hit several keys that I can't find back and I get this
prompt:

[image: Help on my module]

I didn't know it was possible to get this kind of help on a module I am
writing and I have no idea how I got it, so my question is:

What command or tools allows to generate this kind on module information?

**Several notes**

- The command is not a Vim command because the ouput was in an external
  shell (so I probably use an equivalent to `:![command]`.
- I don't have any Vim plugin related to python installed so it was probably not generated by a plugin.
- The command wasn't issued in an interactive python prompt since I started my vim from my bash prompt.
- I have not idea of how many keystrokes I used.
- My Vim command history and my bash history doesn't have a trace of what
  happened.
- I'm using zsh and oh-my-zshell

I know that this question might sound silly but I have no idea of which tool can do that and I have no mean to find what sequence of keystrokes I used.

Comment: **Please** don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's a screenshots of help screen, not code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I understand that a screenshot of text is bad when the other people need to copy the text, but here nobody need to copy it since it's just some help on my own module.

Comment: Why on earth is this question tagged Bash?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Because I didn't know is that was a python command or a bash command and because it happened in bash. But I can change it if needed.

Comment: but you say your shell is zsh… are you confusing bash and shell?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Yep you're right, my mistake sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pydoc` command to get module help

```
pydoc requests
```

if you are using the interactive python shell, you can use the `help` function:

```
>>> import requests
>>> help(requests.get)
```

it work on class instance too

Comment: I don't think it can be that since I started vim from my bash shell I don't think that I could have ended in an interactive python shell. Or could you explain to me how I could have issued this command from Vim?

Comment: @statox `:!pydoc requests`?

Comment: you can run `pydoc` from bash shell, without entering  the interactive python shell.

Comment: Right I get the same results with `:!pydoc boardFrame` thanks a lot! Also I have no idea how I could get that by accident... I probably have a mapping that I'm unaware of.

Comment: `:Pyhelp <string>` (see the [vim faq](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Access_Python_Help)).

Comment: @ahmed: That's the problem, my history doesn't have any trace of `pydoc`.

Comment: @ekhumoro: In your link `Pyhelp` is a user defined command I don't have this snippet in my `.vimrc`. But the link is interesting thanks!